# How to output running sums / counts of multiple types with additional criterion on a separate column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

See the attached screenshot - I'm trying to find a formula to past in column C.

Column B counts how many of a type there are in column A.
Column C is an incrementing number label for each of the types.

[image]

I have tried finding a forumula but haven't been able to yet.

[image: 2]

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 1):

The following works and is not too complicated

```js
=let(input ,A2:A,
     numRow,rows(filter(input,input<>"")),
     result,scan(0,offset(input,0,0,numRow,1),
                 lambda(a,c,if(isblank(offset(c,0,1))
                                      ,if(c=offset(c,-1,0)
                                      ,a+1
                              ,1)
                              ,a))),
     arrayformula(if(isblank(array_constrain(B2:B,numRow,1)),result,)))
```

`offset` lets you access potentially adjacent cells. But it require explicit range. There are only 2 functions that I know of which can output explicit range dynamically: `offset` itself and `indirect`. So we are stuck with that for the 2nd parameter of `scan`.

To use it, (or to use any other alternative within `scan`,) we must use finite ranges. But we want the flexibility of infinite range. So we use `filter` to remove trailing blank cells and `rows` on the result to get the number of rows with content.

`let` lets us define variables inline.

So now we just need to go over `scan`. `scan` lets you maintain and output intermediate accumulators based on the previous accumulator `a` and the current cell `c`. Current cell comes from the range we put into the 2nd parameter.

The `if` statements describe the logic. If previous cell in the same column, `offset(c,-1,0)`, ie. column A, is of the same value of current cell, we want to increment our accumulator by 1, because we are still counting the same Type as before; if different, we refresh the accumulator to just 1.

If the neighboring cell next column, `offset(c,0,1)`, ie. column B, is occupied, we do not do anything and just pass along the accumulator `a`; only when it is blank, we do the previous logic.

The final `arrayformula` phrase just means we will only display the counts if column B is un-occupied.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```cpp
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(τ,LET(ε,OFFSET(τ,,1),IF(OR(τ="",ε<>""),,COUNTIF(A2:τ,τ)-COUNTIFS(A2:τ,τ,B2:ε,"<>")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!

You are much more advanced than me to know these kind of formulas :)
It was looking like it was going to achieve what I wanted but then I found when I applied it to my dataset it has an issue when there are types that have counts that are the same.

I'll put in another screenshot in the original post to show what happens.

I used by the arrayformula and map formula

Comment: Thanks again!

I have a new issue again - If there are two types one after another that have the same count (e.g. pears and strawberries that have 4 each in a new screenshot), then it will sequence them 1->8 instead of 1->4 for each.

I see I keep having the post edited. Sorry I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I understand it's not being posted correctly.

I'm also very appreciative of your help here. I'm happy to pay for consulting on this

Comment: try replacing B2:B with A2:A.

Comment: That works! Thanks again so much.

Okay... I think I have one last condition that I just discovered. But no worries if not, I have a manual workaround which will mean I need to spend 10 or so minutes every every sheet I need to do this for. But, automated would be so awesome

Some entries for the types are actually needing to be excluded (but remain in the list). I'll update the screenshot again.

Is there a way to sequence them with the exceptions excluded?

Again - I'm happy to pay for help

Comment: Amazing!! I'm pretty sure this works for my needs now. I've just tipped you some coffees. Thanks again, you legend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dragging the formula manually (you can also double click on the dot bottom-right of the selected cell),

the following formula works and is simpler:

```js
=if(isblank(B2),rows(filter(A$2:A2,A$2:A2=A2,isblank(B$2:B2))),)
```

To break it down..

**The outer `if`** toggles whether we display anything at all.

**Out of  `filter`** lies the variable we are interested in analyzing: the collection of cells in Column A *so far* that has the same Type as the current cell, hence `A$2:A2=A2`, and whose neighboring B column cell is not occupied, hence `isblank(B$2:B2)`.

Specifically, we want to know, by our current row, how many cells satisfying the above it has been. Hence, **`rows`**.

[image]